# Is it a bug in Hbase REST API `get version/cluster`?

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

Hbase REST API, this interface `get 'version/cluster'`, when I use the header `Accept: application/json`, the response is not JSON but plain text.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  "http://localhost:8888/version/cluster"
# "1.2.2"
```

But when I use `Accept: text/xml`, the response is correct XML.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Accept: text/xml" \
  "http://localhost:8888/version/cluster"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ClusterVersion>1.2.2</ClusterVersion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase issue [#17713](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-17713). The Jan Hentschel's comment, he is right. The JSON spec has been updated from [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) to [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) and a String is valid JSON.

Comment: It's fixed. [#17713](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-17713)